# Value too large for float32

Tags: python, random-forest, decision-tree

I am trying to deploy predictive models on big data. The models i have tried to use is random forest and decision tree, but to no avail. Every time I am getting the same error of too large for dtype float32. So, just want to know that Is there any machine learning predictive models that can handle dtype float64?? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet which triggers the error message you are seeing ? And the error message itself. This helps to understand in detail and answering your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) and enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you *actually* need the full range of `float64` or can the data be normalized somehow? If you're actually using the full breadth of a 64-bit float, then you're going to need a *lot* of data to train a model against all that. I'm talking "store data on every atom in the known universe" levels of "lots of data".

Comment: Sure.. I'll provide code snippets

Answer (score -1):

Try using a data type that has more capacity than float32, like Decimal

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal    
>>> Decimal(2.675)
Decimal('2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
```

Comment: And which machine learning predictive model can use this?